# converting a datetime to string resulting in error "Conversion from string ""dd.MM.yyyy"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."

Tags: vb.net

I have a date, being retrieved from a recordset:

```
AdoRecordSet("Date").Value
```

which has the value:

```
#12/7/2018 12:00:00 AM#
```

When I try to convert it to a string and show it in a textbox:

```
textbox1.Text = AdoRecordSet("Date").Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

This causes an error:

```
Message: "Conversion from string ""dd.MM.yyyy"" to type 'Integer' is not valid."
```

I am trying to figure out why `dtDate.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` is causing the error.

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: @Arvo sorry, I added what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when reading the value from a `ADODB.RecordSet`, it could not be implicitly converted to `Date` from `DateTime`.

It worked with `CDate(AdoRecordSet("Date").Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`